# Apache2 and php won't start after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: apache2, php

I updated to 20.04 and did not test apache2 right away.  However after trying to install php with:

`sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql`

When I try to start with `php` I get:

`PHP Fatal error:  Unable to start pcre module in Unknown on line 0`

And when I look at return from `sudo systemctl status apache2` I get below:

```
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-10-18 04:23:56 EDT; 53s ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 35951 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 35968 (code=exited, status=254)

Oct 18 04:23:56 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Oct 18 04:23:56 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Oct 18 04:23:56 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: apache2.service: Main process exited, c>
Oct 18 04:23:56 coyote-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'ex>
```

The apache2 error.log has the same line from `php`:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Unable to start pcre module in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Unable to start pcre module in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's been a while since the error was reported, you can generally do this to resolve the issue:

```
cd ~
mkdir pcre-bak
cd pcre-bak
mv /usr/local/lib/libpcre* .
```

This will create a directory called `pcre-bak` in your home directory, where you will then move all the `libpcre`-prefixed files from their current directory.

Once this is done, start/restart apache with:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

So long as everything is good, you can delete the `pcre-bak` directory. This happened because PHP made the switch from PCRE to PCRE2 in version 7.3. Ubuntu 20.04 will install PHP 7.4 unless specifically told not to.

If you need PCRE2, you can install it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre2-dev
```